How to run docker compose from sudo crontab?
So, I have a very simple problem: I am running a minecraft network via Docker compose. That compose file is stored in a folder on my user desktop, so it is ./Desktop/.../docker-compose.yaml when I just start it in terminal.
The problem is: my little home server can't be running all night and the compose file has to be executed automatically on boot.
The scripts for Docker have to be stored in sudo crontab and not normal crontab.
How do I execute that docker-compose.yaml from that sudo crontab?
Do I have to do something before I can run the command? [Version of Ubuntu I use is 22.04 LTS]
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Please edit the question and add the version of Ubuntu you are using.

Welcome to askUbuntu @nickycom.  I appreciate you're frustrated with your setup, but please mind your language.  You have not provided us any information with what commands you're using, what version of docker you're using, what the contents of your crontab are.  There are also some serious security implications on how you use and run docker, so that is the reason why docker runs in isolated processes.

Also, askUbuntu is for questions specific to the Ubuntu OS, you might want to ask your question on Stack Exchange sites that have more knowledge about minecraft or docker.  eg https://gaming.stackexchange.com/  https://devops.stackexchange.com/ https://stackoverflow.com/ https://stackoverflow.com/ https://serverfault.com

Final answer to this: Just assign your user to the "docker" group and then write the stuff in the user specific crontab.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
